# How could the energy and cos function be in different shapes?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a code that calculates an integral from zero to pi. But it gives an error which I do not understand how to fix. Thank you for your time.

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi,cos
vtheta=np.linspace(0.0,pi,1000)
def my_function(x):
    Energy = np.arange(2.1,300.1,0.1)
    return ((1.0)/(Energy-1+np.cos(x)))
print (my_function(vtheta).sum())
```

Comment: `Energy.shape == (2980,)`, but `x.shape == (1000,)`, so one has about 3000 elements, and the other - 1000 elements. Now you're doing an elementwise subtraction/addition in `Energy-1+np.cos(x)` - what should the resulting shape be?

Comment: @ForceBru thanks for answering :) i tried this and it worked   :                                   Energy = np.arange(2.1,102.1,0.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is pointed out in the top comment:
Energy.shape == (2980,), but x.shape == (1000,)
so reduce the number of elements in `Energy` or increase `np.cos(x)`.
Since energy is just a numpy arrage i reduced it to size=1000.

In order to fix this they need to be the same size, so this ,for example, works:

```py
import numpy as np
from math import pi,cos
vtheta=np.linspace(0.0,pi,1000)
def my_function(x):
    Energy = np.arange(2.1,102.1,0.1)    #<-- changed 300.1 to 102.1
    return ((1.0)/(Energy-1+np.cos(x)))
print (my_function(vtheta).sum())
```

This is the result (with the above):

```
39.39900748229355
```